# Pass values to a class without editing a record

Tags: apex

I wrote a class that takes a set of ids from the Opportunity and does some actions. The Opportunity Ids are passed when the Opportunity is edited and meets the criteria.

is there a way to pass an id to the class in bulk without editing the Opportunity record?

Example:

Opportunity handler:

```
Set<Id> oppyid = new Set<Id>();
 oppyid.add(Opportunity.Id);
helperclass.methodstart(oppyid);
```

HelperClass:

```
public static void methodstart(Set<Id> oppyis);
 //do stuff...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course. You don't *have* to edit anything. Consider this trivial example:

```
public static void methodStart(Set<Id> opportunityIds) { }
```

As long as you don't make any `update`, `delete`, or `undelete` calls on records gathered using these ids, there will be no edits applied to the records.

Comment: Cool, I was thinking do a anonymous apex to do a query of the ids and then pass them in.